# Can't install Opencv on raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, software-installation, opencv

I'm using the raspberry pi 4 (pip version: pip 22.3.1, python version: 3.9.2) on visual studio code and whenever I enter the command pip install opencv-python in the terminal, after 40 mins I get the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '_skbuild/linux-armv7l-3.9/cmake-install/python/cv2/config-3.py' [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python Failed to build opencv-python ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have found a post on the same problem but the suggestion was to upgrade pip and try reinstalling opencv but that hasn't worked either. I'm using python 3.9.2 as an interpreter

When I use the command pip3 install --no-use-pep517 opencv-python I get the error:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> [6 lines of output] Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 2, in File "", line 34, in File "/tmp/pip-install-zwr61c7o/opencv-python_1867909748974f69a8333e238206f9df/setup.py", line 10, in import skbuild ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild' [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata. ╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip. hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't fiddle with pip; just run

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

which will install the prebuilt wheel

Answer (score 0):

try by clearing cache and direct install by

```
  sudo pip install --no-cache-dir opencv-python
```