# OpenCV Pandas and Numpy

Tags: opencv

I have been trying out some OpenCv snippets as part of a larger robotics project such as Face Detection and Face Recognition. These have all been working on my MacBook.
I am now trying to test out these programs on my Raspberry Pi running Bullseye on a PINN Lite setup.

I have been searching, finding and following various guides on how to install OpenCV correctly, but keep running into problems during installation. When I finally get an install working I then get problems importing cv2, either with numpy or pandas.

I am now following this guide:

[enter link description here](https://raspberrytips.com/install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/)

I am now trying to install using this command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

And noticed after removing the apt version of OpenCV and installing OpenCV through pip, it did not install a newer version of numpy suggesting that a version already existed from opencv-python 1.26.2.

Anyway here is the current output and it always seems to get stuck on

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-python
Using cached opencv-python-4.8.1.78.tar.gz (92.1 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.26.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) ... -
```

This is where it gets stuck?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Opencv on raspberry pi 4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/140517/cant-install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-4)

Comment: Not really - I seem to be going around in an infinite loop. Following the link you supplied I installed opencv using sudo apt install python3-opencv.

Comment: Nope - I am going around in an infinite loop. Following the link I installed opencv using sudo apt install python3-opencv. I then re-ran my program and receive this warning: ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.22.4 your version is 1.19.5. Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.22.4. I then ran pip install numpy --upgrade and then when running my program I get an error with libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory.  I then followed a fix to resolve this which ends up downgrading numpy to 1.19 again and then I'm back with the numpy error.

Comment: If you have run pip you have broken something. DO NOT use pip; get rid of what you installed (or restore from your backup) then install from apt (like the rest of us).