# I cannot install OpenCV on RaspberryPy

Tags: python-3, opencv, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I cannot install OpenCV on RaspberryPi 4 Model B with Bookworm OS. I tried at least 4 different ways including pip and cmake. Each time I reach the step to install OpenCV, it ends in failure: cannot build wheel for Numpy.
I inslalled puthon 3.11.2 and Numpy 1.26.3.
Can anybody help me?
This is one of the procedures I follow:

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm
$ getconf LONG_BIT
64
$ echo $(nproc)
4
$ free -h
total   used   free  shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:   3.7Gi  431Mi  2.8Gi    42Mi       635Mi       3.3Gi
Swap:   99Mi     0B   99Mi

$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git pkg-config
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-numpy
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev  python-numpy
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libswscale-dev libdc1394-22-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev v4l-utils
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libcanberra-gtk* libgtk-3-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libtbb2 libtbb-dev
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
-D ENABLE_NEON=ON 
-D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON 
-D BUILD_ZLIB=ON 
-D BUILD_OPENMP=ON 
-D BUILD_TIFF=OFF 
-D BUILD_OPENJPEG=OFF 
-D BUILD_JASPER=OFF 
-D BUILD_OPENEXR=OFF 
-D BUILD_WEBP=OFF 
-D BUILD_TBB=ON 
-D BUILD_IPP_IW=OFF 
-D BUILD_ITT=OFF 
-D WITH_OPENMP=ON 
-D WITH_OPENCL=OFF 
-D WITH_AVFOUNDATION=OFF 
-D WITH_CAP_IOS=OFF 
-D WITH_CAROTENE=OFF 
-D WITH_CPUFEATURES=OFF 
-D WITH_EIGEN=OFF 
-D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON 
-D WITH_GTK=ON 
-D WITH_IPP=OFF 
-D WITH_HALIDE=OFF 
-D WITH_VULKAN=OFF 
-D WITH_INF_ENGINE=OFF 
-D WITH_NGRAPH=OFF 
-D WITH_JASPER=OFF 
-D WITH_OPENJPEG=OFF 
-D WITH_WEBP=OFF 
-D WITH_OPENEXR=OFF 
-D WITH_TIFF=OFF 
-D WITH_OPENVX=OFF 
-D WITH_GDCM=OFF 
-D WITH_TBB=ON 
-D WITH_HPX=OFF 
-D WITH_EIGEN=OFF 
-D WITH_V4L=ON 
-D WITH_LIBV4L=ON 
-D WITH_VTK=OFF 
-D WITH_QT=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON 
-D BUILD_opencv_java=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_gapi=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_objc=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_js=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_ts=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_calib3d=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_objdetect=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_ml=OFF 
-D BUILD_opencv_world=OFF 
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF 
-D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages 
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=OFF 
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON 
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF 
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF ..
$ make -j$(nproc)
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig
$ sudo apt-get update
$ cd ~
$ sudo rm -rf opencv
$ python3
3.11.2
import cv2

Comment: Does anyone actually read the documentation? If you want to use it install using apt. Why (and how) did you install python 3.12? If you really need to do this you will have to build (and manage) the dependencies in a virtual environment.

Comment: I have to admit that I didn’t read the documentation (of OpenCv if that’s what you asking) but for sure I will read it now. Please be aware that I am not an expert in installation and configuration but I can do some coding. The truth is that I used virtual environment when doing a new installation and I get the same error. So I guess I need some little explanation now: Python and pip are installed first and then everything else will be installed inside the virtual environment or…?

Comment: I was actually talking about the Raspberry Pi OS documentation. If you want to use an extra python version this should also be installed in a virtual environment.

Comment: Edited the question: Actually it's python 3.11.2 ( I think I mistyped two digits, sorry)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Opencv on raspberry pi 4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/140517/cant-install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-4)

Comment: The `python3-opencv` version distributed through the official [bookworm repo](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/python3-opencv) is *4.6* (released in 2022) whereas pypi is currently on *4.9* so for those in need of a less dated version, it would be nice to have access to such also on raspianOS based systems. One workaround which might (haven't tested yet) get one at least to OpenCV *4.8* would be to install Fedora 39 (or rawhide for *4.9*), but it'd be 64bit then as there seems no 32bit release.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have now "I inslalled(sic) puthon(sic) 3.11.2 and Numpy 1.26.3" you have probably made a mess of your system.

I suggest you restore from your backup (or do a fresh install) and start again.

DO NOT attempt to install using pip install using apt.

DO NOT use apt-get use apt.